# Mixing jdbc with hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Background: I am working on a web application, which uses oracle jdbc and access database with java code and also sql queries which will be executed by our engine.

Now I am thinking about "replacing" jdbc over the time with hibernate t have -let's say - hibernate advantages.

My question is, can this be done step by step?

Can I start to create new tables with hibernate and work with hibernate without having risk with the existing database structure? can hibernate works in parallel with jdbc?

Comment: Are you using or planning to use any framework such as Spring?

Comment: at the moment no framework like Spring. Not sure for what it could be good for I don't know it.

Comment: yes using dynamic configruation

Answer (score 3):

The answer is positive.

You can have both jdbc and hibernate data-sources in the same project, no problem.

Just be careful not to mix up those two data-sources, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JDBC and hibernate both can be used in parallel.

However, it depends on use cases. As per your question you just want to *"replace"* JDBC with Hibernate.

So, yes in this case you can start with :

1. creating new tables
2. creating hibernate mapping files
3. creating DAO layer
4. implementing hibernate code.

Comment: Can also the already exisitng tables created by jdbc be accessed using hibernate?

Comment: yes they can be. you have to create your mapping files accordingly.